# A Rogue That Can Heal Themself

Tags: spells, rogue, healing

If I was a rogue that wanted to be prepared, and just know a few healing spells, could I?

Would I be able to be taught by a cleric buddy? Could I take just one lesson at a magic school?

Is it possible to just learn that single healing spell and not have to acquire a magic item or multiclass? I just want to be able to heal troublesome cuts and such.

Comment: Which game and version are you playing? There are many different answers to this question, based on what exactly your game is.

Comment: Well, uh, okay, I haven't...exactly played yet. I've just been dying to and I've half made this character and I just want to be able to have my character prepared. I probably can't actually do anything since I'm just starting but I'd still like to do this. My friend is DMing a game soon and I know he's not using anything specific, so would it be up to him?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Unfortunately, without a system tag on your question, we have no idea what game you’re playing, so we don't know what rules you’re using, so we can’t answer the question. We answer questions about thousands of different games here. So please add a system tag, e.g. `dnd-5e` for the latest edition of Dungeons & Dragons, to your question so we can help.

Comment: Did you build a character for a specific game, or is it just the description of someone without any rules attached?

Comment: Not having played yet is fine, but we do need to know what rules you’re using to prepare the character.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I don't know dudes. If there's no general yes or no, then I think my friend is willing to add it in.

Comment: There's plenty of games where this is easily doable, and plenty others where it is not, so there's no general answer. There's even lots of games where there's no such thing as "magic", or no such thing as "rogues". In general, there are no general answers to RPG questions without knowing the rules system being used. Either way; welcome to the site. This question will probably be closed as being un-answerable, but that's just procedure. Enjoy your first game!

Comment: Consider that asking this without specifying a game is a bit like going into a board game parlor and asking “can I move my piece two spaces?”; you're going to get people asking what you're playing: Monopoly, Risk, Chess, Checkers, Go, etc just for starters—and there's a hundred more games on the shelf. There's thousands of RPGs and all of them are very different from one another. There's no generic answer. It sounds like you're playing Dungeons & Dragons, but we also need to know which edition because the rules for building characters and what features they have available varies each edition.

Comment: Are you playing [this game](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf), or a different game?

Comment: You can ask your friend what game they’re running, then add that to the question. It will be waiting here for you if you want to do that, and can be unheld then.

Comment: I kinda got the message that the question wasn't specific enough, I have to wait 2 weeks until a full answer, but, like I said, thanks anyways